# Deleting items that have been saved using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a table view that has its data saved with the following function.

```
func saveWebsites() {
  let websitesData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(loadedWebsites)
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(websitesData, forKey:       KEY_WEBSITES)
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

I have tried to allow the user to delete an item from the table view, but what happens is that the user can delete an item from the table view, but when the app reloads the item is still there. The code I am using to try and delete it is this:

```
func deleteWebsites() {
  if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(KEY_WEBSITES) as? NSData {
    let site = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
  }
}
```

Anybody know my problem?

Comment: What type is `websitesData`?

Comment: 1) Don't store data in `NSUserDefaults`. 2) Your code in `deleteWebsites` doesn't actually update the data in `NSUserDefaults`.